# External Template in Webpack App Running Marionette

Tags: javascript, templates, dependencies, marionette, webpack

I'm setting up an application with Webpack and running the front-end with Backbone Marionette. I've managed to get the application scripts running [generating a LayoutView within a Controller within the App Module just as in AMD/Require], but what I can't figure out is the **templating**.

In the past, I've used Underscore templates, but webpack prefers Jade and Handlebars. I switched to Jade and still my LayoutView returns the error:

> Uncaught UndefinedTemplateError: Cannot render the template since it is null or undefined.

When I console log out the rendered Jade template I get: `<div class="glossary-container"></div>`

Here's my LayoutView code for review:

```
Marionette = require 'marionette'
AppLayoutTemplate = (require 'templates/appLayoutTemplate.jade')()
console.log AppLayoutTemplate

class AppLayoutView extends Marionette.LayoutView
  initialize: ->
    template: AppLayoutTemplate
    regions:
      glossaryContainer: '.glossary-container'
```

Comment: any view in marionette expect compiled template to render data. By default - underscore compiling to function, this function will be called on rendered with JSON'ed model. In case you need to implement other template engine support you have to re-write Marionette.Renderer

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Handlebars` as a template engine with `Marionette` you need to rewrite a few methods in `Marionette`.

And I suggest you to load templates within marionette and using some kind of caching:

First rewrite [`Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate`](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette#section-196) :

```
Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate = function (yourTemplateId) {

    var yourTemplate, 
        url = 'your/path/to/templates' + yourTemplateId + '.html';

    if (Handlebars.templates && Handlebars.templates[yourTemplateId]) {
        // from cache
        yourTemplate = Handlebars.templates[yourTemplateId];
    } else {
        // from remote resource
      Backbone.$.ajax( {
        async   : false,
        url     : url,
        success : function ( templateHtml ) {
            yourTemplate = templateHtml;
        }
    } );
    }
    return yourTemplate;
};
```

And rewrite [`Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate`](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette#section-197)

```
Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.compileTemplate = function (yourTemplate) {
    if ($.isFunction(yourTemplate)) {
        return yourTemplate;
    } else {
        return Handlebars.compile(yourTemplate);
    }
};
```

After this load your view like:

```
Marionette = require 'marionette'
    class AppLayoutView extends Marionette.LayoutView
      initialize: ->
        template: 'path_to_your_template/without_extension'
        regions:
          glossaryContainer: '.glossary-container'
```

This will work for Handlebars. I am not familiar with Jade, but I'm sure that it should be the same.

Comment: Vahan, thanks for the answer. That will indeed be helpful in the future. The fix was unfortunately a stupid syntax error on my part. Nesting the 'template' hash inside the initialize method when it should have been at the root. For anyone stuck with the same problem I'm going to answer my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a syntax error. I mistakenly nested the `template` hash inside the `initialize ->` method. Answering my own question in hopes that it helps someone down the road.